# Node readFile inside a Loop Memory overflow

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, memory, readfile

I have a folder with 98 .csv files that I need to read and save on a Postgres database.
I'm running this code:

```
// Files in folder
const filesInFolder = fs.readdirSync('../pages-csv');

for (let i = 0; i < filesInFolder.length; i++) {
    console.log(`Saving file ${filesInFolder[i]}`)
    await fs.promises.readFile(path.join(__dirname, `../pages-csv/${filesInFolder[i]}`), 'utf8').then(async (data) => {
        await createOne(data) // database function
    })
}
```

But it leads to this error:

FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory

It seems like files are not closing or not being flushed from memory after inserting in database.

Comment: How large are your CSV files?

Comment: around 680kB to 800kB

Comment: And, how many of these files are there?  And, are you really sending 800kb to the database in one DB call?  That's probably creating some copies of the data just to handle it.  Can you show the DB code inside of `createOne()`.  Does it properly return a promise that only resolves when the DB code is complete?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried streaming it? Something like:

```
var csv = require('csv-parser')
var data = []

for (let i = 0; i < filesInFolder.length; i++) {
    console.log(`Saving file ${filesInFolder[i]}`)
    enter code here

    // add the 'file path here'
    fs.createReadStream(filesInFolder[i])
      .pipe(csv())
      .on('data', function (row) {
        createOne(row)
      })
      .on('end', function () {
       console.log('End cvs')
      })
}
```

Or maybe there is a way to clear the garbage collection:
global.gc(), after you expose it: node --expose_gc

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem, it was the `createOne` function, it had a forEach loop, removed it and now it works!

Comment: This is not a helpful answer if the definition of `createOne()` is not in the question.